# Is there a well-known type of differential equation consisting of $y$, $y'$, and $y''$ multiplied together?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, terminology

Is there some sort of well known type of differential equation consisting of first and second derivatives multiplied together? For example (I just made this up):

$$y''(y')^2-y-x^2=0$$

**Edit:** Are there any applications of these sort of differential equations?

Comment: Consider anything of the form $$ (y^\prime)^k = F(y,x)$$ for some $F$ and integer $k \geq 2$; and differentiate to obtain a new differential equation of the form you seem to seek.

Comment: i don't think there is an explicit solution

Answer (score 1):

The height profile of a [viscous gravity currents on horizontal surfaces](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0022112082001797) can be described using a similarity solution as
$$ (y^3y')' + 1/5(3\alpha+1)xy' - 1/5(2\alpha-1)y = 0, $$

on the domain $ 0 \leq x \leq 1$.  Analytic solutions exist for $\alpha = 0$.

Is this similar enough to what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Tdonut cool. Why are you interested in such an equation?

Comment: I was just wondering if any type like this existed.